# How to fix 'module not found' for audio files using file-loader? Images, CSS, and JSON are working just fine

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mp3, webpack-file-loader

I'm new to building a browser game using Typescript/React/Redux/etc. and am trying to implement audio for the game. I've been attempting to import audio files in the same way I import image and json files, but so far to no avail. After adding mp3 to my webpack config using 'file-loader', I try importing a sample mp3 file I put in the same location as an image file I've been able to successfully import, but when I try to run web pack, it tells me that the mp3 module cannot be found.

sample file

```
import React from "react";
import spriteSheet from "../assets/spritesheet.gif";
import audioFile from "../assets/pillRotate.mp3";

import { Gameboard } from "./Gameboard";

export class MainGameComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <img id="spriteSheet" src={spriteSheet} hidden={true} />
                <audio src={audioFile}></audio>
                <Gameboard />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MainGameComponent;
```

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.tsx?$/, 
                use: "awesome-typescript-loader" 
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|mp3)$/,
                use: 'file-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            hash: true,
            title: 'Dr. Mario',
            template: 'index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/MainGame.tsx:3:23 
    TS2307: Cannot find module '../assets/pillRotate.mp3'.

Answer (score 28):

If you use create-react-app to setup your React project. You can try to add the follow lines in your `react-app-env.d.ts`:

```
declare module '*.mp3' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

When you try to import a `mp3` file in `*.tsx`, typescript compiler will try to find out its declaration, the same way as you import another class file. But when you try to require a `mp3` file, like this:

```
<audio src={require('./assets/xxx.mp3')}>
```

ts will not try to find its declaration, but handle it to webpack loader. This why in this way there is no compile error.

Comment: You are a life saver! `declare module` is required in a TypeScript context. It works with `import` too.

Answer (score 4):

Using `require()` worked for me

```
<img id="spriteSheet" src={require("../assets/spritesheet.gif")} hidden={true} />
```

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and used require for the mp3 and it works!

Any idea why import for the gif works just fine, but trying to import the mp3 the same way doesn't?

Thanks again!

Answer (score -3):

When importing the audio file using Typescript, make sure you don't have brackets around the filename.

```
import audioFile from "./audio_test_sound.mp3"
```